# MS Graph API - Accessing "policies" endpoint with application permissions

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

According to [the docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/policy_list), this endpoint requires **Directory.AccessAsUser.All** which is a delegated permission. Is there any reason why this endpoint doesn't include the application-level permission **Directory.Read.All**?

I understand that this endpoint is still in beta, but where does one make these kinds of suggestions/requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excellent question, there is a [User Voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) set up that covers both Office and Graph developer requests/feedback.

Comment: Thanks, I've now [added this to User Voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/19532443-add-more-permission-scopes-to-policies-endpoint)